# Different layers in Corona/Lua

Tags: events, button, lua, coronasdk

I've got a question about layering images/buttons with Corona/Lua. If I create one button on top of another one and then click it, both buttons' events are triggered. How do I prevent this?

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville

EDIT: Here's how I create the buttons:

```
button1 = display.newImage("button1.png")
button1:addEventListener("tap", Button1Call)

button2 = display.newImage("button2.png")
button2:addEventListener("tap", Button2Call)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return true from the event handling function. Touch events keep propagating through the listeners until handled; it's explained here:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/events-and-listeners#Touch_Events

Note that the event listeners must be listening for the same event. In other words, both listeners must be set on either "touch" or "tap". Literally last night I was tripped up by this; I had a button listening to "touch" and another image on top listening to "tap" and was wondering why the button was still receiving events.

Comment: Thanks @jhocking it really help full for me as i was also facing this issue ....Great!

Answer (score 1):

Use `return true` in the event handler where you handle the event to prevent further event propagation.

So, in your example, `button2` will get the event first, since it's created last.  If you handle the event in `Button2Call` and`return true`, `Button1Call` won't see the event at all.  If you `return false`, or simply leave out the `return` statement altogether, `Button1Call` will get the event and can decide whether to handle it.