# storyboard - multiple scene enterScene/existScene occuring - what's wrong with this code?

Tags: coronasdk

Have spent several hours trying to work out a Storyboard issue here.  I've pruned a sample project down that replicates it.

Issue:

- After going from scene 1, to scene 2, then back to scene 1, and then toggling through scenes a few times I get the following:
- When entering a scene the logging shows multiple enterScene/exitScene are being triggered
- It seems as through perhaps multiple background touch listeners are being registered, however I'm trying to remove these in the exitScene functions
- I'm on the trial version: 2011.704 (2011.12.8)

Output

```
<code>
-- Click on background to go back to screen_example1

storyboard.gotoScene( screen_example1)
screen_example1: enterScene

storyboard.gotoScene( screen_example1)
screen_example1: exitScene
screen_example1: enterScene

storyboard.gotoScene( screen_example1)
screen_example1: exitScene
screen_example1: enterScene

storyboard.gotoScene( screen_example1)
screen_example1: exitScene
screen_example1: enterScene

.
.
.
etc
</code>
```

Code: Three files: main and the two scene files:

main.lua

```
<code>
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
storyboard.gotoScene( "screen_example1" )
</code>
```

screen_example1.lua

```
<code>
local storyboard =  require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local function onScreenTouch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print("")
        storyboard.gotoScene( "scene_towerView")  
    end
end


function scene:createScene( event )
    print ("screen_example1 - createScene")
    local image = display.newImage( "bg.jpg" )
    scene.view:insert( image )
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    print ("screen_example1: enterScene")
    scene.view:addEventListener( "touch", onScreenTouch )
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
    print ("screen_example1: exitScene")
    scene.view:removeEventListener("touch", onScreenTouch)
end

-- Scene Listeners
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )


return scene
</code>
```

scene_towerView.lua

```
<code>
local storyboard =  require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local function onScreenTouch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print("")
        print("storyboard.gotoScene( screen_example1)")
        storyboard.gotoScene( "screen_example1")
    end
end

-- Scene Handlers

function scene:createScene( event )
    print ("TowerScene - createScene")

    -- -- Background Image
    local image = display.newImage( "bg2.jpg" )
    scene.view:insert( image )
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    print ("TowerScene - enterScene")
    scene.view:addEventListener( "touch", onScreenTouch )
end

-- Scene Listeners
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
</code>
```

Comment: PS. Would this issue be because I'm on the trial version?  Is the trial version much earlier than the current stable version?  Any on the latest stable version get the same error I get?

I was going to follow the mooted concept that you could pay for your subscription when you are ready to submit, however if the trial version is way behind in terms of getting hides then I'll Ned to get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding a "return true" at the end of the touch event code? This stumped me for the longest time.

[Different layers in Corona/Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114817/different-layers-in-corona-lua)

k

Comment: it's been a while since I had this issue - I can't quite remember if there was a bug in my code or whether subscribing and moving onto a recent daily build fixed things